# How to stream large files to users local from s3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ecs

I am working on a use case wherein I have a requirement to bulk download 100gb of data from s3 to users local...we have decided to use a ecs and take 10gb of chunks and probably zip them and then send the file to users local

I need some help on knowing if we can zip the entire files and send to users local ?

Or if we chunk out 10gbs and zip one by one how can we send all the zips together to the client?

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried [this approach](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example_s3_Scenario_UsingLargeFiles_section.html)?

As you can see, there are officially supported approaches to upload / download large files in multipart (aka chunk) mode.